# Ndepend reports not showing up in CruiseControl Dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ndepend

I am currently in the process of setting up ndepend report generation as part of Continuous Integration build process using CruiseControl.Net, I have followed the instructions outlined in [ThoughtWorks Website](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+NDepend).

The ndepend tasks runs fine and the reports are generated correctly but when I goto the dashboard and try to bring up the ndepend reports, nothing comes up (it displays blank).  Does the cruisecontrol dashboard application expects the ndepend report in a particular file under the working folder or the artifact folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your xml result files properly merged into the build?

Comment: i have checked the xml result files they are properly merged, the CI runtime doesnot throw any error as well.